# Can I drop PL/SQL procedure in Anonymous block just after called the same procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have created a PL/SQL stored procedure which is used to insert row into related table, then in another PL/SQL Anonymous block, I can call and drop it separatly. But when put these two statements togegher, Sql developer was just continuously running there forever. Below are three code snippets:

-- Below code works well

```
BEGIN
  MyProcedure1 (1,70,'Tommy'); 
END;
```

-- Below code works well

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop procedure MyProcedure1';
END;
```

-- Below code was stuck there forever

```
BEGIN
  MyProcedure1 (1,70,'Tommy'); 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop procedure MyProcedure1';
END;
```

Comment: I can think of no scenario where you would want to do this it would be helpful if you could provide some background information of why you want to do this. This may enable people to give you suggestions on ways to achieve your goals differently / better.

Comment: I have a batch of records to be inserted into table with the specific procudure, this is the requirement from Customer. The procedure has no problem. So I just need write a new script to insert related data with this procedure, and after all these rows are inserted, I also want to drop this specific procedure in the same script,  then ecounter above issue.

Comment: In fact, I have done one related test: I created another procedure (very simple,even has not any parameter), then in another script (Must have Begin  and End, and related statements are just located between them), I call this new procedure then use "Execute IMMEDIATE" dropt the procedure ---- then the result is same, the code was stuck there!

Comment: So the question is just as simple as: In an anonymous block of PL/SQL, can we call a procedure then use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE drop it ? --- this code has nothing related to specific business logic

Comment: Basically, everyone can test it in two minutes in their own environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David, I can still see no reason why after the data is inserted you need to immediately drop the procedure.... what if you want to insert more data tomorrow? Why can you not just manually drop it afterwards if it is just a once off thing?

However if you really must do so...

```
BEGIN
  MyProcedure1 (1,70,'Tommy'); 
END;
/
drop procedure MyProcedure1;
```

Then click run as script button in SqlDeveloper... Runs no issue, looking at session manager what is happening is that the anonymous block is putting the procedure in the cache / pinning it (meaning nothing else can compile / drop it) until that block finishes. This is why moving the drop outside the Begin / End allows the code to work.

Comment: Hi Shaun, Thanks for your solution and explanation! The procedure is just for the insertion of this batch data, and customer do not want run two scripts to complete one task.

Answer (score 1):

If you query `v$session`, this is what you can see (of course, while the anonymous PL/SQL block is still "running" - actually, it is *waiting*):

```
SQL> select
  2    a.blocking_session,
  3    b.username blocking_username,
  4    b.osuser blocking_osuser,
  5    a.sid,
  6    a.serial#,
  7    a.seconds_in_wait,
  8    a.username,
  9    a.wait_class,
 10    a.state
 11  from v$session a join v$session b on a.blocking_session = b.sid;

BLOCKING_SESSION BLOCKING_USERNAME BLOCKING_OSUSER  SID  SERIAL# SECONDS_IN_WAIT USERNAME WAIT_CLASS  STATE
---------------- ----------------- --------------- ---- -------- --------------- -------- ----------- -------
             707 SCOTT             littlefoot       707     1245             329 SCOTT    Concurrency WAITING

SQL>
```

Note the last two columns:

- `state` = waiting
- `wait_class` = concurrency

Who caused it? Me, myself. So yes - we have met the enemy, and they is *us*.

Looks like you can't do it the way you wanted but separately:

- call the procedure first
- once you're done, drop it

---

Though, what a strange requirement ... why would you want to drop a procedure? Will you create it again *tomorrow*? If so, why drop it at all? Saying that "customer requires it" - what the heck customer knows about it? Let them think twice; if that's not enough, think again.

Comment: Hi Littlefoot, thanks for your explanation! The procedure is just for the insertion of this batch of data, and customer do not want run two scripts to complete one task.